# MBP - Switch back to built-in microphone

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have some Apple earplugs with a broken microphone, therefore I cannot talk. I would like to switch back to the built-in microphone. However, there is no option to do so in the Sound System Preferences, and only this is shown:

[image]

And if I unplug the earplugs, I only see the built-in microphone.

[image]

How can I switch to the built-in microphone, when I connect the earplugs?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't; it's a hardware switch, shifts both sources simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple headphones, works
as Combo Jack, ie ear headphone + microphone
external, so you'll have to use another headset.
give it a try.

Comment: I know that. I did mention that they had a broken mic. So, can I change it? Add to answer please

Comment: @thebro21 If I understand the answer correctly, it's not possible to switch only one part of audio if you plug in a combo jack.

Comment: @patrix I see. Thanks for clarification. That does answer my question

Comment: You want to use only
a headphone jack, and built-in microphone?
what version of OS X? El Capitan?